# VS Code noob here, question about launch.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

So far i only wrote c# code in visual studio and for unity. However i decide to work on my C# fundamentals a bit instead of coding only for Unity, hoping to improve my understanding about OOP and designing my objects.

I started to follow pluralsight c# path where dotnet core used with visual studio code instead of regular visual studio. Next 18 hours i actively tried to run Hello World application. After i tried everything google has to offer yet failing, tens of times uninstalling and installing stuff yet failing.I somehow managed to do trick by creating an empty folder at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackagesFallback" by following the tail of error messages.

You may comment something like, "you have learned a valuable lesson" etc. which may be true but i don't want to. I don't want to be an expert at making compilers run, i don't want to learn how they function. I just want to make my code better.

Now i could run Hello World app by using dotnet run from command line where i felt nice, finally i can move on to improve my OOP stuff. But wait VS Code didnt want to proceed.

**After couple hours of tweaking i could finally run the code but i am not happy with it. The reasons why, and what i am asking is below.**

VS Code build .json files with this lines..
tasks.json had `"/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",`
which i had to replace with `"${workspaceFolder}/src/GradeBook",`
and launch.json had

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
```

i had to replace it with

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/GradeBook/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/GradeBook.exe",
```

What i don't mind is adding "/src/GradeBook" only if i have to do that when i use subfolders for project. I don't know if the problem with tasks.json was related to this. But do i have to fully replace tags like `<target-framework>` when .csproj file has a definition of target framework `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>` .

I really do not understand how these .json files work, why auto-generated files do not do their job and how i can live interacting minimally with those. What are the minimal steps i "have" to take care of myself. Can somebody please explain me and please treat me like i am 3 years old with 5 IQ because i fell like one when i am dealing with these stuff.

Comment: What is exactly edited here since it looks exactly like i wrote. And who votes down instead of helping out, any why ?

Comment: you don't need write an essay here with your expressions, just form your questions like that: 1. What I want. 2. What I did. 3. What I see. 
can't read it because too much irrelevant info. I did not downvote but it is probably what others feel too

Comment: vscode builds .json files like '"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",' and expects me to replace it something like '"program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/GradeBook/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/GradeBook.exe",' which takes me obviously hours to figure out. Questions 1) do i have to manually replace everything or am i doing something wrong and things can go more dynamically like tags. Question 2) i really dont understand these stuff so how i can deal with these in future without banging my head to walls all day long.

Comment: would be better if you post your code to github, for example, hard to tell what is the issue without seeing

Comment: you can literally drag n drop files from your computer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206314/discussion-between-pwrigshihanomoronimo-and-kaan-kara).

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a bit more i somehow found this. 
https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/6ozrwj/is_there_really_no_other_way_of_adding_required/

There was a reply

> Adding assets can be done with dotnet.generateAssets command. You can
>   invoke the command using the command palette (Ctrl-Shift-p), search
>   for .NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug.

Which was looking exactly like the thing but unfortunately i got error message :

> "OmniSharp server is not running" / "server has been stopped or not
>   started"

I somehow reached https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/32 where was this comment

> BedmanGit commented on 10 Jan 2019 Add path to environment works
>   http://reddyinfosoft.blogspot.com/2017/07/cannot-start-omnisharp-error-error.html

I added Windows/System32 to PATH. VS Code asked me if i want to generate necessary assets. I clicked yes. My project worked without me having to manually editing .json files.